# Angular Jasmine this service method is a not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to get a service method to pass inside a unit test, however it keeps failing:

"TypeError: this.eventsService.getEvent is not a function"

My code inside my component:

```
constructor(
 private eventsService: EventsService
)

this.subscriptions.add(
  this.eventsService.getEvent().subscribe(events => {
    this.events = events;
    this.soSomeMethod();
  })
);
// Also have a V2 method, unsure if it matters but adding it for clarity
this.subscriptions.add(
  this.eventsService.getEventV2().subscribe(eventsV2 => {
    this.eventsV2 = eventsV2;
    this.soSomeMethod();
  })
);
```

This is the service in question:

```
  public getEvent(): Observable<event[]> {
    return combineLatest(this.store.select(getEventStore), this.store.select(getEvents)).pipe(
      map(state => {
        // do something 
      })
    );
  }
  public getEventV2(): Observable<event[]> {
    return combineLatest(this.store.select(getEventStore), this.store.select(getEvents)).pipe(
      map(state => {
        // do something 
      })
    );
  }
```

My testing has the methods inside the providers:

```
    { provide: EventsService, useValue: { getEvent: () => of([])}},
    { provide: EventsService, useValue: { getEventV2: () => of([])}},
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is Angular is using the last `provider` you have provided for `EventsService`.

To fix it, do this:

```
{ provide: EventsService, useValue: { getEvent: () => of([]), getEventV2: () => of([]) } },
// remove the two instances of EventsService and keep it to one.
```

Comment: Thanks, just adding ```{ functionName: () => of() }``` as useValue made the trick!